# How to detect the name or id of currently running batch job from trigger?

Tags: trigger, batch, triggercontext

Managed code kicks off a batch job.  I have a trigger where I need to do overwrite a field only when it's updated by this batch job.

The only thing I could come up with so far is querying AsyncApexJob, and checking if this particular one is currently "Processing", but that's not good enough, since users could be updating other records that are not in the scope of this batch job at the same time, and this trigger would run.

So, need to know how to detect the batch job in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.isBatch()` method will return `true` if the code was invoked by a batch process.

You could update the field as follows:

```
...
if(System.isBatch()) {
   // Update Field
}
...
```

See: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_isBatch

Comment: I need to enforce this rule not when any batch job is running, but only when this specific batch job is running, and when it's this batch job that is updating the record.

Comment: You would need to know the Job ID from the BatchableContext, or follow @sfdcfox example below using a static variable as a flag. Both of which would need the code to be modified - and you state that this can't be done due to the code being in a managed package. I'm not sure of any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static variable, and check for that variable while in the trigger.

```
public class TriggerFlags {
    public static Boolean isInBatch = false;
}
```

In the batch:

```
TriggerFlags.isInBatch = true;
Update records;
```

In the trigger:

```
if(TriggerFlags.isInBatch) {
    // do stuff here
```

Comment: This is a managed package batch job, so I can't mod its code.

Comment: There's no way to detect, other than simply knowing if you're in batch mode. This is definitely a limitation of the Apex Code language.